# how to make an checkboxlist select only one item selected

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i am using an checkboslist    binding  to  a  datatable.
 but here  i need  to make user  select only one item selected from checkbox list
 is there way  we can aachive this

either  JQuery, javascript, c#
 thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the user is only allowed to select one item from a list, you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

UPDATE:

If you have to use checkboxes then you can use the following code:

```
$("#myform :checkbox").click(function(){
  $("#myform input:checked").attr("checked","");
  $(this).attr("checked","checked");
});
```

Comment: but  my requirment is that i need   to use  checkbox list  not  radio button