# How can I check box list select only one item selected in MCV 3 using jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, checkboxlist

I have developed a MVC3 application in that I want use the Check boxlist in this I have three check boxes. My requirement is when I check the check box it accept only on check box not multiple remaining check box should be unchecked like RadioButton list type.

Please help me... How can I resolve this problem?

Here is my view code

```
           @{
ViewBag.Title = "MenuCategories";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    enable_cb();
    $("#ChbkPickup").click(enable_cb);
});

function enable_cb() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("input.ccc").removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $("input.group1").attr("disabled", true);
    }
}
$(function () {


    $('.example-container > pre').each(function (i) {
        eval($(this).text());
    });
});

 </script>



         @using (Html.BeginForm("OrderCompleted", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" }))
             {
                  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



              Delivery:<input type="checkbox" name="Deliver" value="Deliver" id="Chbkdeliver" />
             Pickup: <input type="checkbox" name="Deliver" value="Pickup" id="ChbkPickup" class="group1"  checked="checked" />
             Dine In:<input type="checkbox" name="Deliver" value="Dinein" class="group1" id="ChbkDinein" />
 }
```

Comment: i ask a question how to make make a single check box checked not multiple..my code accecpt multiple selection. i have searched in google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769621/how-to-make-an-checkboxlist-select-only-one-item-selected .But how can i call this .

Comment: please check that link i want like that way....

Comment: You need to post some code so what we can show you how to call it.  You need to post the HTML and your Jquery for that view.

Comment: ok i updated my code please check it once .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace all your javascript tag with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
      $("#myform :checkbox").click(function(){
        $("#myform input:checked").attr("checked","");
        $(this).attr("checked","checked");
      });
   });

 </script>
```

Comment: is there call any function in my input tag? Because i added this code but i did not find any changes in my action.

Comment: Does the code above allow only one checkbox to be selected at a time?

Comment: i have try using this script but i did not get any action.